# Freeing array of struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, free, alloc

I've done some research and couldn't find any answer to my problem.

I'm having problems with freeing my struct.

This is how i create my struct:

```
struct Structure * newStructure(int N) 
{
    struct Structure * structure;
    int i;
    structure = (struct Structure * ) malloc(N * sizeof(struct Structure));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        structure[i].i_Number = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int));
        structure[i].c_Char = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char));
        structure[i].c_Char[0] = '\0';
        structure[i].d_Float = (double * ) malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
    return structure;
}
```

Everything works to this point. Later I fill every variable with random values so that they are not empty.

I call my `freeMemory` function like this `freeMemory(structure, amountOfStructures);`
And here is freeMemory function itself:

```
void freeMemory (struct Structure* structure, int N)
{
    int i;

    for( i=0 ; i<N ; i++ )
    {
        if (structure[i].i_Number!=NULL) free(structure[i].i_Number);
        if (structure[i].c_Char!=NULL) free(structure[i].c_Char);
        if (structure[i].d_Float!=NULL) free(structure[i].d_Float);
    }

    free(structure);
}
```

The free(structure) part works fine. But there are problems with the for loop and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

@EDIT
I'm adding my struct declaration:

```
struct Structure{
    int *i_Number;
    char *c_Char;
    double *d_Float;
};
```

@EDIT2
That's the function that initializes struct:

```
    struct Structure* randomizing (int N)
{
    struct Structure* structure = newStructure(N); int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int _i; char _c; double _d;

         _i = rand()%1000000;
         _c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" [rand () % 26];
         _d = 0;

        setStructureNumber(structure, i,(int*) _i);
        setStructureChar(structure, i, (char*) _c);
        setStructureDouble(structure, i, &_d);
```

### ***// I'VE COMMENTED OUT THE MUTATORS ABOVE AND THE ERROR DOES NOT SHOW ANYMORE, SO THERES SOMETHING WRONG WITH THEM***

```
    }

    return structure;
    }
```

And im calling it like this:

```
    struct Structure* structure;
    structure = randomizing(amountOfStructures);
```

The mutators used:

```
// Mutators
void setStructureNumber (struct Structure* structure, int p, int* num)
{
    if (structure[p].i_Number != NULL) free(structure[p].i_Number);

    structure[p].i_Number = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
    structure[p].i_Number = num;
}

void setStructureChar (struct Structure* structure, int p, char* str)
{
    if (structure[p].c_Char != NULL) free(structure[p].c_Char);

    structure[p].c_Char = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
    structure[p].c_Char = str;
}

void setStructureDouble (struct Structure* structure, int p, double* dou)
{
    if (structure[p].d_Float != NULL) free(structure[p].d_Float);

    structure[p].d_Float = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double));
    structure[p].d_Float = dou;
}
```

Comment: There are a few things you should be aware of: a) you're not checking to see if the original allocations succeed, any access of the pointer after that point is undefined behavior as the memory may... or may not have been allocated. b) Free doesn't care if you pass it a `NULL` value, if you do it just does nothing.

Comment: Show your `struct Structure` definition. It is very strange that inside the allocation cycle you are allocating just one object of each type for each struct field. `malloc(sizeof(char))`- seriously? Are these fields really declared as pointers? And if so, why?

Comment: Could you add your struct here ?

Comment: I've added edits so that maybe someone finds the problem :x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that somewhere in your code you go out of bounds of the memory you allocated and thus destroy the integrity of the heap. A frequently encountered practical manifestation of such undefined behavior is a failure at `free`, when the library detects the problem with the heap.

Inside you allocation cycle you allocate just one object of each respective type for each field of your  struct object. For example, you allocate only one character for `c_Char` field and initialize it with `\0`. This might suggest that `c_Char` is intended to hold a string (is it?). If so, then the memory you allocated is sufficient for an empty string only. If you do not reallocate that memory later, any attempts to place a longer string into that memory will break the integrity of the heap and trigger undefined behavior.

The same applies to other fields as well. However, without extra explanations from you it is not possible to say whether it is right or wrong. At least, you have to provide the definition of `struct Structure`. And you have to explain your intent. Why are you dynamically allocating single-object memory for struct fields instead of just making these objects immediate members of the struct?

---

The additional code you posted is completely and utterly broken.

Firstly you are calling your mutators as

```
setStructureNumber(structure, i,(int*) _i);
setStructureChar(structure, i, (char*) _c);
setStructureDouble(structure, i, &_d);
```

This does not make any sense. Why are you trying to convert integer value `_i` to pointer type??? If you want to obtain a pointer to `_i`, it is done as `&_i`. You already do it correctly in the very  last call, where you pass `&_d`. Why are the first two calls different from the last one? What was your logic behind this?

Secondly, inside your mutator functions

```
void setStructureNumber (struct Structure* structure, int p, int* num)
{
    if (structure[p].i_Number != NULL) free(structure[p].i_Number);

    structure[p].i_Number = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
    structure[p].i_Number = num;
}
```

you are freeing old memory and allocating new memory. Why? Why don't just reuse the old memory to store the new value? (BTW, there's no need to check the pointer for null before calling `free`, because `free` will check it internally anyway.)

Thirdly, after allocating the new memory you immediately leak it by overriding the pointer value returned by `malloc` with the pointer value passed from the outside

```
structure[p].i_Number = num;
```

Again, this does not make any sense. This is actually what causes the crash on `free` - the pointers you pass from the outside are either meaningless random values (like your `(int *) _i` or `(char *) _c`)) or point to a local variable (like your `&_d`).

---

There's no way to "correct" your code without knowing what it is you are trying to do in the first place. There are just too many completely unnecessary memory allocations and reallocations and other illogical things. I would simply rewrite the mutator functions as

```
void setStructureNumber (struct Structure* structure, int p, int num)
{
    *structure[p].i_Number = num;
}
```

Note - no memory reallocations and the argument is passed by value.

The functions would be called as

```
setStructureNumber(structure, i, _i);
setStructureChar(structure, i, _c);
setStructureDouble(structure, i, _d);
```

But again, this is so vastly different from what you have that I don't know whether this is what you need.

Comment: It is not intended to hold a string, just a single char. I've placed \0 there just to fill the variable. Should've deleted that.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating single-object memory for struct fields instead of just making these objects immediate members of the struct?  - Thats what I got told to do, I'm not sure its the right way to do it. If you can, I will be really grateful for any explanation how I can do it better since I really want to learn it.

Comment: @itzathis: What I meant is that you could simply declare your `struct` as `struct Structure { int i_Number; char c_Char; double d_Float; };`. No pointers inside struct. That way you wouldn't have to allocate and free the second-level memory at all. But whether this is the right thing to do depends on your intent, which is still not entirely clear.

Comment: @itzathis: But in any case, everything you have so far looks perfectly fine. The problem is in some other code.

Comment: I've added an EDIT2 with the rest of the significant code that may cause errors, can you take a look at it?

Comment: Thank you! Everything works now : ). I'm so confused with C, managing pointers, allocating etc seems so crazy.

Comment: @itzathis: As I noted in my comment above, you can improve it even further. Get rid of the pointers in the structure: `struct Structure { int i_Number; char c_Char; double d_Float; };` and get rid of memory allocations for struct members. Inside your mutator functions just assign values as `structure[p].i_Number = num`. After that your program will have only one `malloc` for the struct array and one `free` for the struct array.

Comment: I would totally do that, however my assignment says i need to do it this way. But I've created my own upgraded version based on your comments : D. thanks once again!

Comment: "The most likely reason is that somewhere in your code you go out of bounds of the memory", with one sentence you finish 2 hours of headache in 5sec

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with what you are doing (except the missing error checks on allocations, unnecessary casts of `malloc` results, and unnecessary `NULL` checking before calling `free`).

This should work fine, assuming that you pass the correct value of `N`, and that you do not free things more than once:

```
struct Structure * newStructure(int N) {
    struct Structure * structure = malloc(N * sizeof(struct Structure));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        structure[i].i_Number = malloc(sizeof(int));
        structure[i].c_Char = malloc(sizeof(char));
        structure[i].c_Char[0] = '\0';
        structure[i].d_Float = malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
    return structure;
}

void freeMemory (struct Structure* structure, int N)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++ )
    {
        free(structure[i].i_Number);
        free(structure[i].c_Char);
        free(structure[i].d_Float);
    }
    free(structure);
}
```

You can use a memory diagnostic tool such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to ensure that you do not freeing things more than once.

Comment: `structure[i].c_Char[0] = '\0';` is especially error prone. segfault may occur.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr You mean because `malloc` returns `NULL` on the line above? All unchecked `malloc`s are prone to this, not only this one. OP allocates a single-character string to `c_Char`, so there will be no segfault unless `malloc` failed to allocate memory for it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight true, however the easy solution is to use `calloc` in that particular case to ensure it's zeroed if the allocation succeeds.

Comment: the c_Char is supposed to hold just a char, not a string. It was my mistake to put \0 there, I totally forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Mgetz: `calloc` will properly zero-out `int` and `char`, but is not guaranteed to properly zero-out `double` objects. For IEEE754 `double` it will work, but C language does not require IEEE754 representation.

Comment: @itzathis It's not a mistake at all: your `c_Char` is a C string, which must be null-terminated. You allocated a single `char`, which is the smallest thing that you could allocate to hold a valid C string (because you need at least one spot for the null terminator). Then you put a null terminator in there, so you are fine.

Comment: Okay, based on the comments that issue may be present somewhere else, Ive added the rest of the significant code.

Answer (score 0):

In your mutators you leak memory and then point to local variables (comments mine)

```
void setStructureChar (struct Structure* structure, int p, char* str)
{
    if (structure[p].c_Char != NULL) free(structure[p].c_Char);

// allocates new memory and points c_Char at it.
    structure[p].c_Char = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));

// makes c_Char point to where `str` is pointing; now the allocated memory is leaked
    structure[p].c_Char = str;
}
```

When you later do `free` on `structure[p].c_Char`, it causes undefined behaviour because you called this function with a pointer to a local variable.  You probably have undefined behaviour elsewhere too if you try to access `c_Char` anywhere before freeing it.

The other mutators have the same problem.

To "fix" this change `structure[p].c_Char = str;` to `*structure[p].c_Char = *str;`.

You also have blunders here:

```
setStructureNumber(structure, i,(int*) _i);
setStructureChar(structure, i, (char*) _c);
```

You meant `&_i` and `&_c` respectively.  I would advise to **remove all casts** from your code. At best they are redundant; at worst (e.g. in these two lines) they hide an error which the compiler would diagnose.

Also remove all the NULL checks before `free`, they are redundant and make your code hard to read. Instead, do the NULL checks *after* calling `malloc`, and abort the program if malloc returned NULL.

However this whole setup seems like a ghastly design. You could pass the things by value to the mutators. And you could change your struct to not contain pointers, and therefore not need all this extra allocation.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway I can remove (char*) from:
 structure[p].c_Char = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
?

Comment: Yes, move your cursor to after the `)` and press Backspace several times

Comment: so placing (char*) there does not change anything?

Comment: Having it there in the first place is a bad idea, [see here for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)